# Can I submit duplicate image, video, and content sitemaps to Google Webmaster Tools?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, sitemap

Can I submit 3 duplicate sitemaps (image, video, content) which have same URLs to Google Webmaster Tools?

#### Image Sitemap 1:

```
<loc>http://mywebsite.com/article1</loc>
<video:video>
 ....
</video:video>
```

#### Video Sitemap 2:

```
<loc>http://mywebsite.com/article1</loc>    
<image:image>
....
</image:image>
```

#### Content Sitemap 3:

```
<loc>http://mywebsite.com/article1</loc>
<loc>http://mywebsite.com/article2</loc>
<loc>http://mywebsite.com/article3</loc>
```

Comment: Don't image sitemaps need to contain the image URLs (ending in `.jpg` or `.png`) and not the article URLs?  https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/178636?hl=en

Comment: Hello, image URLS and article URLs is required

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't submit the exact same sitemap (same syntax, same URLs), and expect Google to sort out what kinds of assets you're trying to identify.

If you submit a sitemap that you intend to be for your videos, and it doesn't have the required Video sitemap syntax, and contain the required video-specific tags, Google won't see it as a video sitemap.  It's just a duplicate sitemap.

If you want the benefit of better discovery, better indexation, etc, that comes with submitting a sitemap, you have to follow the syntax **exactly**. Bing have stated that if the error rate on a sitemap exceeds 1%, they begin to treat it as "untrusted".

Video sitemaps: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/80472?hl=en

Image sitemaps: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/178636?hl=en

Comment: Hello, it is my mistake. I edited my post. I mean I use different syntax (video, image, content), just use same URL. It is allow by Google ?